# SQL - select person in the same group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS SQL Server 2017. I have table named Persons with columns: `id`,  `name` and `group`. The column `id` is a primary key.

I need to select person and other persons names who in the same group.

Example:

Data in table Person:

```
Id | name  | group
1  | Alice |  2
2  | Bob   |  2
3  | Jane  |  2
4  | Fred  |  3
5  | George|  3
```

Expected output of select:

```
id | group |  name  |persons in the same group
1  |  2    |  Alice |{Bob, Jane}
2  |  2    |  Bob   |{Jane, Alice}
3  |  2    |  Jane  |{Alice, Bob }
4  |  3    |  Fred  |{George }
5  |  3    |  George|{Fred }
```

Comment: What are the ids of bob and jane? And what to do with them?

Comment: just for example Bob id = 2, Jane id = 3. Bob and Jame both have group = 2.
@SalmanA

Comment: Please show us a dozen rows with good sample data that represents all edge cases and the final result that you expect to get based on that sample data. Right now your example is not clear.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A correlated sub query or cross apply could be used to find the *other* persons:

```sql
select p1.*, (
    select string_agg(p2.name, ', ') within group (order by p2.name)
    from persons as p2
    where p2.[group] = p1.[group] and p2.id <> p1.id
) as [others in the same group]
from persons as p1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an aggregation query:

```
select 1 as id, p.group, string_agg(p.name)
from persons p 
where p.group in (select p2.group from persons p2 where p2.id = 1)
group by p.group;
```

Comment: I am not sure that you answer is correct and in this table not only one person with id = 1. In your asnwer everything associated with id = 1

Comment: @ШебаловДенис . . . Your question implies that you are looking for the other people in the groups with person 1.

Comment: Excusme, no. I am trying to say that i need list all perons and other persons names that are in the same group.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this one:

```
select p.id, p.group, string_agg(p1.name, ',') as persons_in_group
from persons p
left join persons p1
on p.group = p1.group and p.id != p1.id
group by p.id, p.group
```